# Firebase hosting : customize directory page or get JSON?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

If I navigate in a browser to a directory page (e.g. `www.my-site.com/files`) of a project hosted with Firebase hosting, I get a list of files in that directory, which for my use case is desired behavior.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to customize the directory page at all, such as adding styling or a link back to the home page?
2. Or to have visits to the directory return `JSON` of the directory contents, so I can `fetch` it?
3. Are there any guarantees about the appearance or behavior of directory pages?

There's nothing in the docs about this, so I assume the answer is no, but would like to be wrong!